# forward localhost to ipadress on local netwerk

Tags: nginx, debugging, web-testing

I have a domain name registered and i made an A record on it that points to 127.0.0.1 (aka localhost). I want to be able to work on websites in this case from machines that are in the same network as the server its running on but those servers are not open to the public internet. I still want to use my test subdomain to access this website but that would point to the machine im working on at that time so it must forward the requests to an 192.168.*.* ip adress I have set entered on the machine. Is there a windows command i could use that forwards localhost to a specific ipadress, like linux has 'iptables'? Or a program that could do this? Preferably for free.
I dont want to add my internal ipadress to a dns record because that would be sensitive information.

Comment: No. This is impossible. There is nothing sensitive about your internal non-routed `192.168.x.x` address, so you should go exactly this way to achieve what you want.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem should not tried to be solved this way in any case.

Comment: Why would the website respond to your test name?

Comment: But just stating it shouldnt be solved this way isnt helpfull at all. Im sorry for asking this question but there is no need to attack me. 
And its not a weird thought to not provide outsiders info about your internal network, as DNS info is accessible for everyone.

Comment: I was looking for this because it seems like a more proffesional and elegant solution than just using ipadress. And with that I can also setup nginx to do certain things based on the (sub)domain name.
I have seen serveral other websites link a test subdomain to localhost but I wanted to try to forward it to a specific test server without having to rely on changing dns records because they can take up to 24 hours to change

Comment: Would it be best to setup a local web server and then forward the traffic to my test server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about adding an entry to `/etc/hosts` (linux) or `c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` (windows) ?

The format is: `<ip address> <servernname>`, e.g.: `192.168.10.12 www.stackoverflow.com`.

Once you did that, accessing `http://www.stackoverflow.com` from the machine where the `hosts` file has been edited will end up being served by the server running on `192.168.10.12`.